# How can I convert a string to a json string with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example: now my string is

```
aa, bb, cc
```

How can I convert it to

```
[{"name","aa"},{"name":"bb"},{"name":"cc"}]
```

with SQL Server

Comment: Either split the string and use `for json` or just manually alter the string with replace.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is using String split and JSON path function.

```
create table jsonprac
(name varchar(100) )

insert into jsonprac values ('aa,bb,cc') 

select   
(select s.value as [name]   from  jsonprac p 
 cross apply string_split(p.name,',') s
 for json path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) JsonValue
```

Output:

```
JsonValue
[{"name":"aa"},{"name":"bb"},{"name":"cc"}]
```

Comment: Of course, this *only* works in SQL Server **2016 or newer** which has the `for json path` clause